# Cannot install Bluemix tool plugin on eclipse(Mars)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, ibm-cloud

As mentioned in the Bluemix guide, I tried installing the Bluemix tool plugin on eclipse(Mars) with Java 7 installed on my Ubuntu machine.

1). Through the eclipse market place where Bluemix tool is present and the same fails with the following error when installation is nearly over:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: IBM Bluemix Tools 1.0.5.v20150801_1001 
(com.ibm.cftools.feature.feature.group 1.0.5.v20150801_1001)
Missing requirement: Bluemix Tools 1.0.6.v20150801_1001 
(com.ibm.cftools.branding 1.0.6.v20150801_1001) 
requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jst.server.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Cloud Tools Branding UI Plugin 1.0.2.v20150801_1001 
(com.ibm.cftools.branding.ui 1.0.2.v20150801_1001)
To: package com.ibm.cftools.branding.internal 0.0.0
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: IBM Bluemix Tools 1.0.5.v20150801_1001 
(com.ibm.cftools.feature.feature.group 1.0.5.v20150801_1001)
To: com.ibm.cftools.branding.ui [1.0.2.v20150801_1001]
```

I checked this exception and found a description about it in the eclipse web page. However, the remedy is missing for this particular problem.

2). Besides I tried to install the same via WASdev, but I ended up with the following error:

`No repository found at http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/cloud/V1.0`

However, the same page is accessible from any web browser. Also, I have checked my proxies and they are fine.

Please let me know if there is any solution or what I am doing wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Eclipse for Java EE Developers edition? It is required that edition to satisfy some bundle requirements.

Comment: I use Eclipse Mars (4.5, Build id: 20150621-1200) Eclipse IDE for Java Developers edition. I decided to use this version of eclipse since the same was recommended in Bluemix web site.

Comment: Reading Bluemix docs: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/deploy_eclipsetools.html you will see for Java EE Developers edition is required. It is the edition that supports servers view which is required.

Comment: I got it after some time and going to install Java EE Developers edition and try the same. Thanks.

Comment: After I tried with Java EE Developers edition of eclipse and got special privilege from admin to access all required urls, I successfully installed Bluemix. Please mark it as solved. Thanks Chemi.

Comment: @KumaravadivelTS you as the owner of the question should mark the answer as correct. I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

A few pointers:

- An Eclipse update site needs to have a site.xml - check if the location actually has one.
- Your install error points to a missing jst component. That's Eclipse "core" stuff. So it seems your access to the original Eclipse update site needs to be checked
- Check your Eclipse install, do you have rights to all the files?

Hope this helps

Comment: I have checked your pointers and I see a site.xml file in the mentioned path. Yes, I have root privilege. Though I haven't installed any plugins, I will check with fresh eclipse installation.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine I installed Eclipse below my home by unzipping the eclipse.zip as regular user. No root required. I found installing Eclipse using apt-get troublesome

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the error message you are receiving (not able to resolve  "org.eclipse.jst.server.core") is due to the installation process not being able to locate this package. This package is provided by the same Eclipse marketplace entry or DHE update site from which you are installing (and so you should not see this error when installing from our marketplace or update site). I have confirmed that the provided update site URL is correct and installation works as expected on my own Ubuntu installation.

A few other suggestions, or for users that see the same problem:

- This may be a hiccup with DHE or with your connection to the update site. I would suggest trying the installation again.
- Try a fresh install of Eclipse to ensure that no other dependencies are interfering with your installation. The Java EE package 'Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers' available for download from Eclipse.org will include the required package that is mentioned in your error message (though as previously mentioned, this should not be necessary as this package is bundled with our update site/marketplace entry).
- Ensure you are NOT using the default version of Eclipse available from the Eclipse Software Center, which is often several versions behind.

If this doesn't help, feel free to provide more information about your current installation (version details, method of installation, any other details) to help us reproduce.

Comment: Initially, I was not even getting the market place plug-ins list and after keep on trying the same was displayed. :) I use ubuntu Release 12.04, 64-bit Mars (4.5, Build id: 20150621-1200) Eclipse IDE for Java Developers edition.

Comment: It's a fresh IDE and yet to install any plug-ins on it. Method of installation is help->eclipse marketplace -> search specific plug-in and click install. Please let me know if I am missing here.